# migrating htaccess from Apache to nginx

Tags: nginx, php, .htaccess, apache-2.4

I'm trying to start using `Homestead` for my non-Laravel projects (**legacy**) and I managed to install box `0.3.3` successfully by cloning `laravel/homestead 2.2.1` (with PHP 5.6.15).

Now my problem is due to `.htaccess` configuration. The one I use works for Apache, but is giving me `No input file specified` in Nginx (at Homestead).

The .htaccess I'm using is as follow. The goal is

- allow browser to load/download some specific extension
- disallow any load/download for specific folders (`config` and `email`)
- Redirect to `index.php`

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule !\.(ini|js|ico|gif|jpg|png|css|html|swf|flv|xml|csv)|^[config/*|email/*]$ index.php
```

I tried online tools to convert like [Anilcetin](http://www.anilcetin.com/convert-apache-htaccess-to-nginx/) and [winginx](http://winginx.com/en/htaccess) with no luck.

In my server, I'm suppose to load URLs like `/user/panel` and `/user/manager/shop` and the `index.php` file knows how to read that from the URL and load the correct page.

Comment: That bit of .htaccess is redundant. Just drop it. Your `try_files` will send everything to index.php.

Comment: @MichaelHampton you seem to be absolutely right. I removed the htaccess completely and I'm getting the same error `No input file specified`.

Comment: That's a completely different issue than the one you've asked about. Consider posting a new question.